# Candidate score is given incorrectly for users with less than 1k points

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, candidate-score

The candidate score displayed on election pages contains a reputation points component of 1 point for each 1k reputation points up to a maximum of 20.

However, for candidates with less than 1000 reputation points it seems the reputation points are used directly and without capping in the computation of the score, giving very wrong scores.

**Example 1:** On the currently ongoing Russian Stack Overflow election, there is a [candidate with 556 reputation, and the candidate score shows up as "557/40"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-729505). See screenshot below:

[image: Reputation 556, candidate score 557]

**Example 2:** On the page of the [2014 Mathematics Stack Exchange Elections](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5) there are two candidates with less than 1000 reputation points and for them the reputation points seem to be used directly and without capping as candidate score.

For example [there is a candidate with 667/40 candidate score](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5#post-1059459); they have 663 reputation points.

Comment: It does appear to be an issue in 'live' elections; [a candidate in the Russian Stack Overflow election](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-729505) has a score of 557/40. Some further digging (+ Google Translate) shows [this bug report](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6103) for the issue.

Comment: It's sad that they're not elected even with 667/40 score

Comment: To note I think mathematics now have a minimum of 3k to apply for the election. I dont know if its a trend that will generalize

Comment: @yagmoth555 It's 1k, not 3k (which is of course sufficient to prevent the issue from occurring). Only SO requires 3k rep.

Comment: @Desire strictly, it is not sufficient to prevent it down the road as reputation can also decrease over time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, in the attempt to fix a different issue, this broke.

All fixed now.